# Heimdall errors

Tags: custom-roms, recovery-mode, heimdall

Doesnt work.

trying to install a new recovery rom on a samsung s4 i9505

```
heimdall flash --recovery openrecovery-twrp-2.6.3.0-jgedlte.img
Heimdall v1.3.1, Copyright (c) 2010-2011, Benjamin Dobell, Glass Echidna
[url]http://www.glassechidna.com.au[/url]

This software is provided free of charge. Copying and redistribution is
encouraged.

If you appreciate this software and you would like to support future
development please consider donating:
[url]http://www.glassechidna.com.au/donate/[/url]

Initialising connection...
Detecting device...
Claiming interface...
Setting up interface...

Checking if protocol is initialised...
Protocol is not initialised.
Initialising protocol...
ERROR: Failed to initialise protocol!
```

Comment: This error is apparently common when drivers are missing or not configured. What operating system are you running on your computer? If you're using Windows, you will also need to get the Samsung USB Drivers. http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks/Samsung-Andorid-USB-Driver-for-Windows Let us know if that's not the issue!

Comment: I tried it on my imac and installed samsung kais on it

Comment: If I recall correctly, a Mac shouldn't need the USB drivers. I know this is probably a dumb question because your output says `Detecting device...` without any errors, but have you tried a different USB cable?